# Issue with loading images on Chrome bowser Version 75.0.3770.80 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, lazy-loading

With lazy loading some images were loading some were not on **Chrome Browser Version 75.0.3770.80 (Official Build) (64-bit)**.

The code was -

```
<img class="card-img-top lazy" data-src="/Path to image">
```

And in script -

```
new LazyLoad();
```

I have upgraded the plugin from **11.0.3** to **12.0.0**, but it did not help.

Currently I have disabled Lazy loading on our site. Can any one tell me what could be the issue?

I have also create an issue on [Github](https://github.com/verlok/lazyload/issues/350)